# Rsync - file ownership, group membership not preserved

Tags: linux, rsync

I want to use rsync to backup files from a 'source server' to a 'destination server'.  It appears rsync is not preserving file ownership and group membership.  It is also likely I am not running the command correctly...

**Source files on source server**

File attributes of source.

```
[maintenance@tver-test maintenance]$ pwd
/home/maintenance/
[maintenance@tver-test maintenance]$ ll
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 2 maintenance maintenance   6 Mar 20 10:08 2019-03-01
drwxr-xr-x. 2 maintenance maintenance   6 Mar 20 10:08 2019-03-02
drwxr-xr-x. 2 maintenance maintenance   6 Mar 20 10:08 2019-03-19
drwxr-xr-x. 2 maintenance maintenance   6 Mar 20 10:08 2019-03-20
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 maintenance maintenance 123 Mar 20 10:34 test.sh
```

**Rsync command**

```
[maintenance@tver-test ~]$ sudo rsync -avzL /home/maintenance/* /mnt/Backups/$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
sending incremental file list
created directory /mnt/Backups/2019-03-27
test.sh
2019-03-01/
2019-03-02/
2019-03-19/
2019-03-20/

sent 318 bytes  received 101 bytes  838.00 bytes/sec
total size is 123  speedup is 0.29
```

**Files as they appear on mnt**

If I read [rsync man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) correctly, -a should include -o and -g, preserving ownership and group membership, but when I view the files on the destination, everything is root.  It maintained time, why not not owner or group?

```
[maintenance@tver-test ~]$ cd /mnt/Backups/2019-03-27/
[maintenance@tver-test 2019-03-27]$ ll
total 1024
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   0 Mar 20 10:08 2019-03-01
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   0 Mar 20 10:08 2019-03-02
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   0 Mar 20 10:08 2019-03-19
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   0 Mar 20 10:08 2019-03-20
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 123 Mar 20 10:34 test.sh
```

Please educate me on what I am missing!  Currently guessing it has to do with -o super-user only, but I don't know enough to be certain...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What filesystem is `/mnt/Backups/`? NTFS?

Comment: source file system is xfs, destination file system is ext4.